# Change int color opacity in java/android

Tags: java, android, int, transparency, alpha

I am trying to change the opacity of a color that I get of my theme with the next code:

```
TypedValue typedValueDrawerSelected = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValueDrawerSelected, true);
int colorDrawerItemSelected = typedValueDrawerSelected.data;
```

I want that the `colorDrawerItemSelected` keeps the same color, buth its alpha should be 25%.

I found some solutions getting the rgb color from the imageView, but I havent imageView.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Dahnark It's very much possible.

Comment: it's just **ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wouldn't it be sufficient?

```
colorDrawerItemSelected = (colorDrawerItemSelected & 0x00FFFFFF) | 0x40000000;
```

It saves the color value and sets the alpha to 25% of max.

First byte in the color int is responsible for the transparency: 0 - completely transparent, 255 (0xFF) – opaque. In the first part ("&" operation) we set the first byte to 0 and left other bytes untouched. In the second part we set the first byte to 0x40 which is the 25% of 0xFF (255 / 4 ≈ 64).

Comment: Can you give me a link that show how to use that combination of "&" and "|". I am newbie in Android and I would like to know to understand it (I saw that symbols other times).

Comment: @Dahnark It is bitwise operations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation "&" – bitwise AND. "|" – bitwise OR.

Answer (score 17):

I use this approach in my app:

```
private int getTransparentColor(int color){
    int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
    int red = Color.red(color);
    int green = Color.green(color);
    int blue = Color.blue(color);

    // Set alpha based on your logic, here I'm making it 25% of it's initial value. 
    alpha *= 0.25;

    return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
}
```

You can also use [ColorUtils.alphaComponent(color, alpha)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html#setAlphaComponent(int,%20int)) from the support lib.

Answer (score 15):

Use ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(color, alpha) to set the alpha value to a color easy. The ColorUtils class is in the android support lib.

Comment: Thanks! This should be the current accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
int[] attrs = new int[] { android.R.attr.colorPrimary };
TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int colorPrimary = a.getColor(0, 0);
a.recycle();
```

Now you can change the opacity of `colorPrimary` by updating the highest 8 bits:

```
//set new color
int newColor = (colorPrimary & 0x00FFFFFF) | (0x40 << 24);
```

Comment: Thank you too :) but I used the code of Sergey because it is simpler.